# Why map() operation on a javascript array to copy it to another array after changing an element returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let array = [
  { id: 1, name: "One" },
  { id: 2, name: "Two" },
  { id: 3, name: "Three" },
];
```

I have this array, I want to copy it to another array after changing one element, but my code does not work out.

```
array_copy = array.map((element) => {
  if (element.id === 2) {
    element.name = "name changed";
  } 
});

console.log(array_copy);
```

I am getting this output--

```
(3) [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

I am new to js and self learning it, can u pls help me understand this?

Here is the link of the question
[Copy javaScript array by changing one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524121/update-array-containing-objects-using-spread-operator)

--I tried to answer . What is wrong with my logic/approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change your source array you have to copy element from the source array and return the copied and modified elements instead.

```js
let array = [
  { id: 1, name: "One" },
  { id: 2, name: "Two" },
  { id: 3, name: "Three" },
];

let array_copy = array.map((element) => {
  let copy_element = Object.assign({}, element)
  if (copy_element.id === 2) {
       copy_element.name = "name changed";
  } 
  return copy_element ;

});

console.log('array_copy', array_copy);

console.log('array',array);
```

Comment: var numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];

var newarray = numbers.map((num) => num * 10);
console.log(numbers);
console.log(newarray); ----- here the main array remains ualtered. Pls tell me whats going on.-- what was the diff bw my code and this piece of code. Seems same.

Comment: But numbers are primitives. But `element` in the map function it's a reference to the original element. So you have to think about that when you modify the elements through the iterations. Sometimes it's what you want, sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Hmmmm, yes I understood that. So it works same as Java in this case.I didn t want that behavior in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return something from the function you are using for the map-callback

Do this instead:

```
array_copy = array.map((element) => {
  console.log(element.id);
  if (element.id === 2) {
    element.name = "name changed";
  } 
return element
});
```

As you are not returning anything from the function, you are getting undefined for each iteration

Comment: I was confused with how thew arrow function works in js, for single line of code in method body return statement is optional, but here I had to mention it. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `return` statement otherwise it will be `undefined` as expected but Array map changes the main array elements so log the main `array` and see you'll get modified it also.

```js
let array = [
  { id: 1, name: "One" },
  { id: 2, name: "Two" },
  { id: 3, name: "Three" },
];

array_copy = array.map((element) => {
  if (element.id === 2) {
    element.name = "name changed";
  } 
  return element;
});

console.log(array,array_copy);
```

Comment: yes it works, but method definition says map() does not change the original array. Pls visit the link for method description--[ https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp ]

Comment: Yes, i said that it works, but I want to know how, If u visit the link and see the examples there the main array remains unaltered

Comment: var numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];

var newarray = numbers.map((num) => num * 10);
console.log(numbers);
console.log(newarray);
here the main array remains ualtered. Pls tell me whats going on.

Comment: Does this has something to do with primitive datatypes and objects?I am from java background so I am trying to compare and learn js. Pls help me understand this.

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee actually you're not modifying main array with map, you're modifying internal objects of it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35922654/1138192

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the return statement, thats why you getting undefined.

this is the correct code

```
array_copy = array.map((element) => {
  console.log(element.id);
  if (element.id === 2) {
    element.name = "name changed";
  } 
return element;
});

console.log(array_copy);
```

Comment: Yes its working, But I have one doubt- as mentioned in one of the answers that the map() alters the original array, and surprsingly it is doing so, but when i look at how the `map()` works online , there main array remains unaltered.

Comment: Map is pure function, Its alway return a new array. here is link for more details - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map